# Can a real number be transformed to a complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers, real-numbers

I'm trying to completely understand how the complex plane functions and how transformations work in the plane. I understand how taking a complex number $a + bi$ and raising it to an exponent will multiply the angle by that exponent and exponentiate the magnitude. Through this, I'm wondering is there a way that a real number $x > 0$ can be transformed to a complex number directly, instead of, for example, multiplying by $-1$ and taking the square root? In other words, can we use any operation to turn that real number into one with a complex part?

Edit: I think this may clear it up - for any complex number, we are able to transform it through exponentiation because $\theta > 0$, but here, I don't see any way to perform a rotation in the complex plane if a point lies on the positive real axis.

Comment: You could add $i$ to it. That'll give any real number a nonzero complex part.

Comment: True, you're right. Please see my edit.

Comment: This is really what you’re asking: Is there a real number that when raised to the power of a real number gives a nonreal number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each complex number Z can be shown as $Z=x+iy=r*e^{i*\theta}$
Now let's say you have real number x
You can clearly see that the distance of x from 0 is x which you can translate as radius.
Now all you have to do is to multiply x (or r as we said) by $e^{i*\theta}$ where $\theta$ is the angle of your complex number from the x axis

Example:
I have real number x=5 and I want to show it as complex number where the angle of this number would be 30
So the transformation of it would be 
$5*e^{i*30}$ (you should transform your $\theta$ to radians, will be better to express with radians)

Answer (score 1):

A real number is just a complex number with a zero magnitude for the imaginary component.

Another way of saying this is that a real number r is actually:
$$r=R\angle 0$$

So go ahead and multiply the zero angle by any exponent you want.  You won't get off the real axis...

Comment: That's a good point. So then why is something like $i$ explained as the halfway point between -1 and 1 if you can only reach it from -1 and not 1?

Comment: @rb612: To get from $1$ to $-1$ you rotate the plane 180 degrees, to get from $1$ to $i$ you rotate the plane 90 degrees. To “reach $w$ from $z$” in this context, you don't raise $z$ to a power, you multiply $z$ by some complex number.

Answer (score 0):

You can go like this:

first consider R as a real number, let cosθ=R/2 ,so we have $R=e^{iθ}+e^{−iθ}$.

In general,let $R=re^{iθ}$, and $r=e^{iα}+e^{−iα}$. Then
$R=e^{i(θ+α)}+e^{i(θ−α)}$